# I can not get result every time I run data report . How can I fix this ?

Tags: vb6

I want to make a report of daily income expense account. I am using a `data environment` for this report and made date field as group field. The problem is that every time I run the program the data sometimes appears and sometime it's showing just blank. I can't understand why this is happening and what is the reason for it? 
I have bind table directly through data environment tool 
code is here

> > Private Sub CmdOk_Click()
> >
> > Dim RsRojmelIncome As New ADODB.Recordset
> >      Dim RsRojmelExp As New ADODB.Recordset
> >      Dim RsTempRojmel As New ADODB.Recordset
> >         cn.Execute "delete from TempRojmel"
> >
> > RsRojmelIncome.Open " select * from Rojmel where Date1 BETWEEN #" &  Format(DTPicker1.Value, "MM/DD/yyyy") & "# AND #" &
> >     Format(DTPicker2.Value, "MM/DD/YYYY") & "# And IncExp = 'ytJtf'", cn,
> >     adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
> >
> > RsRojmelExp.Open " select * from Rojmel where Date1 BETWEEN #" & Format(DTPicker1.Value, "MM/DD/yyyy") & "# AND #" &
> >     Format(DTPicker2.Value, "MM/DD/YYYY") & "# And IncExp = 'SJtf'", cn,
> >     adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
> >
> > Set RsTempRojmel = New ADODB.Recordset
> >
> > RsTempRojmel.Open "Select * from TempRojmel", cn, adOpenKeyset,  adLockOptimistic
> >
> > If RsRojmelIncome.RecordCount >= 1 Then
> >
> > For i = 1 To RsRojmelIncome.RecordCount     RsTempRojmel.AddNew     RsTempRojmel.Fields("Id") = i     RsTempRojmel.Fields("IncVigat") =
> >     RsRojmelIncome.Fields("Vigat")     RsTempRojmel.Fields("Date1") =
> >     RsRojmelIncome.Fields("Date1")     RsTempRojmel.Fields("IncAmount") =
> >     RsRojmelIncome.Fields("Amount")     RsTempRojmel.Update
> >     RsRojmelIncome.MoveNext
> >     Next i
> >     End If
> >
> > If RsRojmelExp.RecordCount >= 1 Then
> >
> > For j = 1 To RsRojmelExp.RecordCount     RsTempRojmel.AddNew     RsTempRojmel.Fields("Id") = j     RsTempRojmel.Fields("ExpVigat") =
> >     RsRojmelExp.Fields("Vigat")     RsTempRojmel.Fields("Date1") =
> >     RsRojmelExp.Fields("Date1")     RsTempRojmel.Fields("ExpAmount") =
> >     RsRojmelExp.Fields("Amount")     RsTempRojmel.Update
> >     RsRojmelExp.MoveNext
> >     Next j
> >     End If
> >
> > If DataEnvironment1.rsCommand1_Grouping.State = 0 Then
> >
> > DataEnvironment1.rsCommand1_Grouping.Open " SHAPE {SELECT * FROM `TempRojmel`}  AS Command1 COMPUTE Command1, SUM(Command1.'IncAmount')
> >     AS Aggregate1, SUM(Command1.'ExpAmount') AS Aggregate2,CALC
> >     (Aggregate1-Aggregate2) as NetProf1  BY 'Date1'  ",
> >     DataEnvironment1.Connection1, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
> >
> > End If
> >
> > RptRojmel.Sections("Section7").Controls.Item("Text1").DataField = DataEnvironment1.rsCommand1_Grouping.Fields("NetProf1").Name
> >
> > RptRojmel.Sections("Section7").Controls.Item("Text2").DataField = DataEnvironment1.rsCommand1_Grouping.Fields("Aggregate1").Name
> >
> > RptRojmel.Sections("Section4").Controls.Item("LblDate1").Caption = DTPicker1.Value
> >
> > RptRojmel.Sections("Section4").Controls.Item("LblDate2").Caption =  DTPicker2.Value
> >
> > RptRojmel.Refresh
> >     DataEnvironment1.rsCommand1_Grouping.Requery
> >     RptRojmel.Refresh
> >     End Sub

Comment: hi guys ! anybody know about it ?

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
If DataEnvironment1.rsCommand1_Grouping.State = 0 Then

  DataEnvironment1.rsCommand1_Grouping.Open " SHAPE {SELECT * FROM      TempRojmel} AS Command1 COMPUTE Command1, SUM(Command1.'IncAmount') AS Aggregate1, SUM(Command1.'ExpAmount') AS Aggregate2,CALC (Aggregate1-Aggregate2) as NetProf1 BY 'Date1' ", DataEnvironment1.Connection1, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

End If
```

try Using

```
If DataEnvironment1.rsCommand1_Grouping.State = adStateOpen Then

  DataEnvironment1.rsCommand1_Grouping.Close

End If

DataEnvironment1.rsCommand1_Grouping.Open " SHAPE {SELECT * FROM      TempRojmel} AS Command1 COMPUTE Command1, SUM(Command1.'IncAmount') AS Aggregate1, SUM(Command1.'ExpAmount') AS Aggregate2,CALC (Aggregate1-Aggregate2) as NetProf1 BY 'Date1' ", DataEnvironment1.Connection1, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

Comment: Thank for your reply but its working in debug only not working with F5 :( my problem is still remaining !!